# Windows 10, how not to combine buttons on taskbar?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I have Windows 10 build 15063.138. How do I have Windows not combine buttons on taskbar? In Settings/Taskbar, the "combine buttons on other taskbars" option is gray out.

Comment: If you are having a bit of trouble with the registry updates, it may be easier to download and utilize the batch files found here:  [How to Always, Sometimes, or Never Combine Taskbar Buttons in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/25732-always-sometimes-never-combine-taskbar-buttons-windows-10-a.html)

Answer (score 2):

There is a registry setting that enables or disables this feature. You can use the Registry Editor (Start > Run > regedit) to edit the following keys:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoTaskGrouping

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoTaskGrouping
```

By setting their value to "0", you will be able to select the grouping options in the taskbar properties.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I tried regedit and found nothing under CurreentVerion\Policies (HKCU). It couldn't be expanded. Should I right click and add a new key?

Comment: HKLM does have \Policies\Explorer but there is no NoTaskGrouping key. Should I add one?

Comment: @yky - Yes. It *should* force whatever is disabling the dropdown menu to be overridden. If the second one doesn't work by itself, try creating the missing tree needed for the `HKCU` hive. Remember to **restart your computer** after each change so that it can be properly applied to `explorer.exe`.

Comment: Should NoTaskGrouping be a DWORD?

Comment: @yky - Yes, a DWORD with a value of 0 (decimal).

Answer (score 0):

It's different between "Grouping of Taskbar Buttons" & "Combining of Buttons".

To disable "Grouping of Taskbar Buttons", under the following key

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
```

set NoTaskGrouping DWORD to 1
(remove it to enable)

To disable "Combining of Buttons", under the following key

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
```

set MMTaskbarEnabled DWORD to 1
and MMTaskbarGlomLevel DWORD to 2
(remove them to enable and restarting Explorer task is required)